# Remove everything but certain characters from a string | Python

Tags: python

How would I remove everything but certain characters from a string such as (+,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)

math = ("tesfsgfs9r543+54")

output = ("9543+54")

Comment: Try something like `output = re.sub("[^+0-9]", "", math)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

```py
import re
output = re.sub("[^+0-9]", "", math)
```

Using iterators is also possible, but it probably is slower. (not recommended)

```py
output = ''.join(ch for ch in math if ch in "+1234567890")
```

Using a for loop.

```py
def keep_characters(string, char_collection):
    result = ""
    for ch in string:
        if ch in char_collection:
            result += ch
    return result

output = keep_characters(math, "+1234567890")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last two code fragments test for `ch in "+1234567890"` (instead of `not in`)?